# JMSSerializer - Custom handler for a property

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I know that I can declare a custom handler for a whole type. But what if I want to use different approach for serializing the same type in different situation?

For example I have an entity, it has a property `int $popularity`. But I want serializer to process it first (for example multiply it by 2).

Classes:

```
class Foo {
    public int $popularity = 10;
}

class PopularityProcessor() {
    public function process (int $popularity) { return $popularity * 2; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
App\Entity\Foo:
    properties:
        popularity: ~
```

Here, when serializing to json, I don't want the serializer to just use `$foo->popularity` to get the value of the property. Instead, I want it to do something with the value and then return, e.g.

```
return $this->popularityProcessor->process($foo->popularity);
```

Since `$popularity` is an integer, I can not register a custom handler for it. What can be the solution?

Comment: Maybe using this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#converting-property-names-when-serializing-and-deserializing

Answer (score 1):

You could use Virtual Properties for this case.
This means you add a method in the Foo class which calls to the processor or do the logic directly in the method.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  public int $popularity = 10;

 /**
  * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
  */
  public function processPopularity(): int
  {
    return $this->popularity * 2;
  }
}
```

You could use the [Serialized Name](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname) to make it available as "popularity" and exclude the property from serializing.
You can find information about it there:
https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty

Comment: Yup, it works for simple cases when I can count it inside the entity. But what if I need some services to do some processing? Not just count in a method, but call a separate service to do something to that field.

Comment: Then I would use an Event Listener: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system#register-an-event-listener-or-subscriber